# Lots of user initiated XeLaTex compiling tasks, how to speed up the server?

Tags: xetex, compiling

I’ve developed a web application, which allows an user to generate PDF-based documents and whole ebooks. Or atleast its current iteration is finalized enough for the time being. Decorating and layoutting is handled by a typesetting engine named XeTeX and content is *internally* formatted with XeLaTeX. However, the compiling phase is too slow and I need a lot more speed. In some sense my question about how to speed things up might fit to some other community in the StackExhange, but there might be something spesific about XeLaTex that you might be better aware of.

Slightly irrelevant, but the website introducing the web application can be found here: http://sovelluksien.hoito.org/kotvawrite/index.html

The user interface has multiple screens, which allow focusing to certain kind of tasks at a time. The screen, wherein the decorating and layoutting is done, has quite a lot of buttons, which change how certain document or the whole book will look like (headers, fonts, image borders etc.). Every single change takes some time. Sometimes it is a matter of milliseconds, sometimes it is few seconds or so. And that's just for a single chapter of a book or for a single document.

The slowness might partly be circumvented by using more powerful CPU, faster disks/memory, file caching etc. Network latency doesn't matter so much as the data sent as JSON isn't very large in size and preview images load quickly.

Because there would be lots of combinations to try, if there were tens or even hundreds of fonts, only a few carefully selected ones are offered for an user to try as he/she probably wants to match them with line spacing, chapter name's styling, page numbering etc. There are also settings for image placement, number of columns, page size and few more fancy ones.

Every single change results in generating of a PDF-file (e.g. chapter of an ebook), which is stored on a server, after which an user will see PNG-versions of all the generated pages on certain place of the user interface (scaled down in size, scrollbars and zooming functionality available).

Well, it seems like my question could be reduced to this: if the aim is to speed up XeLaTex compiling (generally), how much would I have to be prepared to pay for a suitable (CPU, disks, memory?), high performance "bare metal" server having CentOS as the operating system? Would I still be left disappointed?

Comment: One thing to know about XeTeX is that it creates the PDF in two steps; it first creates an XDV file then passes that file to `xdvipdfmx` to generate the PDF. So one way to speed things if you run xelatex more than once to build a given file, is to pass the `-no-pdf` option to avoid creating the PDF, and then manually call `xdvipdfmx` on the resulting XDV file after the final xelatex run.